# How to make a grouped and stacked bar with Google charts?

Tags: charts, grouping, stacked

I read the entry from 2016 (How to make a grouped bar stack with Google charts) about this problem and I try the solution described, but I have problems!
When I try the solution, my second stacked bar is overwrite the first bar, you can see it in the attached pictures.
It would be great if anybody can help me!
Peter

I try the solution , which are described in the entry with the same question.

Here the first picture with the data for the first bar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uRmz.jpg)

And here the second picture including the data of the second picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhxOz.jpg)